# SQL parameters in Databricks

Tags: sql, scala, databricks

```
%sql

  INSERT INTO db.table_name1 info VALUES
  ('A','B','2019-01-01 00:00:00.000'),
  ('A','C', '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000'),
  ('A','D', '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000')
```

I would like to use parameter for all same dates.

```
  INSERT INTO db.table_name1 info VALUES
  ('A','B',date),
  ('A','C',date),
  ('A','D',date)
```

Tried using

val date = '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000'

and getting error

Comment: Could you please share the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
%scala

val dt = "2019-01-01 00:00:00.000"
spark.conf.set("da.date", dt)

%sql

create table table_name1 (name string, name1 string, ts string)

INSERT INTO table_name1 VALUES
  ('A','C','${da.date}'),
  ('A','D','${da.date}')

select * from table_name1
```

Comment: I tried this solution but I am getting this error                               
 ```Legacy SQL widgets are no longer supported. Please update your code to specify values using current SQL widgets.
Error in SQL statement: DateTimeException: Cannot cast  to TimestampType. To return NULL instead, use 'try_cast'. If necessary set spark.sql.ansi.enabled to false to bypass this error. ```